# solve a series of systems of linear equations with similar structure efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to obtain the least squares solutions of systems of linear equations in the form of $$A_\alpha x = b_\alpha$$
where $A_\alpha$ is a $m \times n$ real matrix for $\alpha \in [0,1]$   and $m > n$.

$A_\alpha$ is$$A_\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
 \alpha A_{11}  & A_{12}\\ A_{21}  & A_{22}\\   & A_{32}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A_{ij}$ is some fixed real matrix.

I currently solve these equations using loops for many $\alpha$, but it is time-consuming. Is there any tip that can be used to solve these equations effciently?

Many thanks！

Comment: I would be very surprised if this was possible. Even in the corner case of m=n=1 I do not see any possibilities. Does $A_{11}$ have full column rank? What are the dimensions of all the named blocks. Is there any additional information that you can share with us? What is the underlying problem what produced this least squares problem?